# php replace {rrggbb} colors in string to color text with <span>

Tags: php, regex

I receive text from a game which uses color embedding in text to color messages, you just use it like this: {ff0000}red text {00ff00}green text

I want to output such string via php and have it properly colored.
So the above string turns into this

```
<span style="color: #ff0000">red text </span><span style="color: #00ff00">green text</span>
```

I have some ideas about this (like I know that the first match of the color needs to be replaced to `<span ..>` and any next occurrence needs to be replaced to `</span><span ...>` to close the previous span tag, and that another span closing tag needs to be added to the end of the string if at least one match was found.
I could probably over-complicate this and do this manually with loops and comparing the text, but that would be complicated and probably inefficient.

How could I do that with some regex functions (and possibly a loop) in php?

Comment: Lot easier to use a Dom parser.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Not a job for a DOM parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not HTML parsing at all and RegEx is best suited tool here:

```
{([a-fA-F0-9]+)}((?>[^{]*{?(?!(?1)}))*)
```

Breakdown:

```
{   # Match `{`
    ([a-fA-F0-9]+) # Match and capture hex color code
}   # Match `}`
(   # Capturing group #2
    (?> # Start of a non-capturing group (atomic)
        [^{]*   # Match anything up to a `{`
        {?(?!(?1)}) # Match it if not going to contain a color code
    )*  # As much as possible, end of NCG
)   # End of CG #2
```

[RegEx live demo](https://regex101.com/r/cgDCdU/1)

PHP code:

```
$text = <<< 'TXT'
{ff0000}red tex {00ff00}green text
TXT;

echo preg_replace('~{([a-fA-F0-9]+)}((?>[^{]*{?(?!(?1)}))*)~',
        '<span style="color: #$1">$2</span>', $text);
```

[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/FvKn0)

Comment: beautiful anwser and explaination :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer full of lessons!

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this :

```
$str = '{ff0000}red text {00ff00}green text' ;
$str = preg_replace_callback('~\{([^\}]*)\}([^\{]+)~', function($matches) {
    return '<span style="color:#'.$matches[1].'">'.$matches[2].'</span>' ;
}, $str) ;
echo $str ;
```

Outputs:

```
<span style="color:#ff0000">red text </span><span style="color:#00ff00">green text</span>
```

Comment: What if text contains Unicode characters, symbols... punctuation marks?

Comment: @revo You're right. I know. This is a solution for the given example. Thanks for this interesting question.

Comment: Anwser updated to use other characters... Except `{`.

Comment: Now it got better. +1